# Why does my application crash when it tries to open a file after the phone restarts?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application that recieves a file from the user and inserts the URI into a SQLite db:

```
    public void getBook(){                     // called when the user wants to give a file to the app
        Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        chooseFile.setType("text/plain");
        chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
        startActivityForResult(chooseFile, FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri u = data.getData();
            addBook(u);   // addBook adds u.toString() to the db
        }
    }
```

My application uses the following code to read the file (it gets `u` by using `Uri.parse()` on the string from the db):

```
    private void readFile(Uri u, String lang, String name){
        try {
            InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(u);  //the code crashes on this line
            \\ some code...
        }
        catch(java.io.IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.file_not_found, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

This works fine even when I reopen the app, but after the phone gets restarted I'm getting the following error:

```
2020-03-06 11:31:49.687 5664-5664/com.example.android.readme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.readme, PID: 5664
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{93bfa52 5664:com.example.android.readme/u0a163} (pid=5664, uid=10163) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2013)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1959)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:4758)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5836)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2526)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1780)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1394)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1247)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:967)
        at com.example.android.readme.MainActivity.readFile(MainActivity.java:162)
        at com.example.android.readme.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:25)
        at com.example.android.readme.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:84)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1158)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3127)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4042)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Why does it happen? (I do use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` in my code.)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What android version is crash happening on, might be helpful to check the updated guidelines on working with files and storage https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: @JimmyFlash Android 8.1.0

Comment: Check using FileProvider api, https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/share-files-using-fileprovider

Comment: @JimmyFlash it is written in the post linked to your comment that "ContentProvider is an Android component which encapsulates data and provides it to other applications", but I don't want to share a file with any other apps... So why may it be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
addBook(u);   // addBook adds u.toString() to the db
```

By default, your rights to access the content identified by the `Uri` is limited to the activity instance that was given the `Uri` via `onActivityResult()`. In particular, your rights go away when your process does.

If you are going to persist the `Uri` from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and try to use that `Uri` again the next day/week/month/year, you need to call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on `ContentResolver` first, before saving your `Uri` to the database.